Should what can’t be impossible be preferred over what may be impossible?
This came up from a discussion on another thread and it got me thinking. There are certain things we know to be possible. For example, we know that it is possible for life to arise completely by chance, even if we consider it to be a low probability.
On the other hand, life arising by design may be impossible. Can we prove that it is impossible? No. But it may be, since we don’t know if any extraterrestrial or supernatural designers with these capabilities exist (or even can exist).
Note that life arising by chance can’t be impossible. Since we know that it can atleast arise by it given our knowledge of scientific laws, even if people consider it to occur with a very low probability.
So this brings up the question: should what can’t be impossible be preferred over what may be impossible?

Hello Hart. PhilSE is a Q&A site that deals in relatively brief, fact-based questions and not open-ended philosophical discussion. I recommend to everyone who wants that using The Philosophy Forum where questions like the one you posed are encouraged. See our help center for more details. And don't take votes for closure personally. A good question is hard to write.

No, not in this generality. If doing nothing leads to certain death but doing something gives a chance to survive one should certainly prefer the latter.

@JD I can see why this question might need to be closed, but I think its flaws are such that an answer which isn't opinion based can be provided, so I tried to provide one. Let me know if you think I should delete it.

@gs From a strictly game theoretic standpoint, you shouldn't delete answers to questions that are closed. You can receive upvotes on good answers to bad questions, and despite the policy against doing philosophy in the FAQ, why not benefit from an abortive question? Personally, I almost never downvote an answer, and I certainly would want the OP to receive the benefit of answers even if the question itself is out of bounds. :D I encourage you to answer your heart out to every and any question and let the community vote on it.

"Note that life arising by chance can’t be impossible. Since we know that it can atleast arise by it given our knowledge of scientific laws" - This is completely wrong. Where did you get if from? Regarding the origins of life, science has only speculations.

@Conifold what you said fits with the scenario though, or at the very least doesn’t contradict it. A chance to survive = it can’t be impossible to survive. Doing nothing = certainly impossible to survive. What can’t be impossible is preferred over what may be (in this case certainly) impossible.

Basically none of the OP assumptions are true.  Under reductive materialism, where life is a biochemical machine, all the models we have today for how abiogenesis could have operated -- do not actually work.  No, we don't know that under reductive materialism that life is evolveable.
There is a similar conclusions for emergent physicalism, and emergent dualism.
While under idealism and spiritual dualism, life is not material, so none of the biochemistry even matters to whether something is alive or not, and life evolving materially would be impossible.

We don't know the ontology of our universe. Under none of these main options, is it known that life could in principle evolve biochemically.
However, given the materialist presumption of life being a biomachine, all one would need for an agent hypothesis is for a being which can build bio machines. There is no logical objection for human technology advancing to the point that we can construct new cellular entities -- we are already close -- which would be creating life.  So we actually know agent creation is possible in principle

There is likewise no logic prohibition to spiritual or ideal life creation.  These points invert your argument.  It was a bad argument anyway, as it is based on a confused understanding of probabilities, but if it actually WERE valid, it would lead to the opposite conclusion you argue for.

Or, it may be impossible to survive, but the death can't be impossible and so 'should' be preferred. Which suggests that the question is altogether meaningless and depends on how one phrases the "impossibles".

"... may be impossible..." is an oxymoron because "may be" and "possible" are synonymous. You might as well say "Possibly not possible" or in more lay language "Maybe, maybe not" [Addendum: "Maybe, maybe not" in common usage signifies "Maybe or maybe not" ie. a tautology. But here it would be "Maybe and maybe not" — a contradiction]

@Conifold What? Give me a real world example of what you just said and you’ll realize it doesn’t contradict the scenario I mentioned. Living forever “may be” impossible (since we’ve never observed this). Dying can’t be impossible (since we’ve observed it). When it comes to believing whether or not someone will eventually die, one should believe that they will.

We also don't know that a time before last Tuesday existed, or even could have existed. See: Omphalos hypothesis and reactions thereto.
Things which can't be impossible (even if there wasn't any time before last Tuesday) are things which are necessary. All things which are necessary are actual. Nothing is necessary which is contingent.
To know that something is necessary is to know that it is true, so the title question reduces to: "If something is true and we know it, should we believe it?"
The body of the question contrasts two hypothetical contingent facts. One which is contingent on certain hypothetical non-necessary conditions. One which is contingent on certain hypothetical non-necessary beings. Since they are contingent, they aren't relevant to questions about necessity.

Additional problems:
They also aren't contradictory hypothetical contingent facts. There are four possibilities, not two. There could be conditions and no being; there could be no conditions save for the being; one of the conditions could be a being; or there could be a being whose method was to set the conditions.
The first paragraph also includes a falsehood. We have no model which says, even probabilistically, "given such and such conditions, life will follow upon non-life." We have a guess that we will one day have such a model.

See? +10. Keep hacking away at philosophy!

I think you’re missing the point of the question. We may not be able to know whether something will happen. But we can atleast know if something will happen with a p > 0. The probability of a dice roll landing on 6 is certainly 1/6. We have seen it happen. The probability of an angel controlling a dice roll may be 0. Thus, what can’t be impossible should be preferred over what may be.

@HartLort I haven't rolled any dice since well before last Tuesday.

Sorry, that was a bit flippant. If you're trying to compare what can be modeled with model + angels, you're looking for Bayes' Theorem. If you're trying to compare angels with kinematics, I think you'll discover that you just have two names for the same set of rules.
